# error 404 after removing public/index.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, deployment

I just wantet to test a simple rails app on my new VPS-Server with Ubuntu 12.04, Apache and PhusionPassenger.

Everything works fine with the default index.html file in the public directory.

But if I remove this file and try to render files from the view-directory I get and 404 Error.
On my local machine everything works...

I thought, maybe it has something to do with the asset pipeline, so i tried "rake assets:precompile" but it didn't help.

Edit: I have set the correct root path, with action and method.

Comment: Did you remember to set a new `:root` in your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: I have no other routes. I just created a default rails app and wanted to test everything on the webserver. I generated a controller and a template, removed the public/index.html and updated the routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem:

Logfiles showed "application.css isn't precompiled".

instead of: `rake assets:precompile` I used `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and now it works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have not set root_path in your app. You can set it like this `:root => "controller_name#action_name"`.

Answer (score 0):

The index.html file is the default substitute for your root url.

So when you removed it, then there is no route that handles the root url (/).

To set the root URL (/), any of these routes will do:

```
root :to => 'controller#action'
root => 'controller#action'
get '/' => 'controller#action'
```

Comment: my root URL in routes.rb is correct. If I run rails server on my local machine everything works just fine. Only after deployment on the server I get the error. If I have the public/index.html on the server it also works...